# Material 3 colorSchemeSeed and having plain black and white theme

Tags: flutter, material-design

With Material 3, colorSchemeSeed can be used to set the color for the entire app. This works for colors like Red, Blue, and Green. If left as default the color will be purple. When trying to use black color as a seed, the color defaults to purple.
What would be the best way to have the Material 3 app, but have the color of the app Theme be plain black and white (in light and dark mode)?

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way would be to setup your ThemeData colorScheme manually.
This is for light theme, you can just set Brightness.dark and swap around black and white for dark theme

```
ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primary: Colors.black,
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
          secondary: Colors.white,
          onSecondary: Colors.black,
          error: Colors.red,
          onError: Colors.white,
          background: Colors.white,
          onBackground: Colors.black,
          surface: Colors.white,
          onSurface: Colors.black,
        ),
        textTheme: textTheme,
)
```

Comment: This does work indeed. Thank you for suggesting this as an alternative. It just seems like an odd way to get black or grey buttons. Perhaps this is the way Flutter and Material 3 teams intend people to create black buttons.

Answer (score 2):

To further build on what seanyyyyy answered I archived the black and white look I wanted with the following theme inputs.

```
final Map<int, Color> color = {
    50: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .1),
    100: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .2),
    200: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .3),
    300: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .4),
    400: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .5),
    500: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .6),
    600: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .7),
    700: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .8),
    800: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .9),
    900: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
  };

  final Map<int, Color> colorWhite = {
    50: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .1),
    100: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .2),
    200: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .3),
    300: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .4),
    400: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .5),
    500: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .6),
    600: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .7),
    700: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .8),
    800: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .9),
    900: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
  };

theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
      secondaryContainer: Colors.grey,
      primary: MaterialColor(0xFF000000, color),
      surface: MaterialColor(0xFFFFFFFF, colorWhite),
      surfaceVariant: MaterialColor(0xFFFFFFFF, colorWhite),
      onSurface: Colors.black,
    ),
    tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
      labelColor: MaterialColor(0xFF000000, color),
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: MaterialColor(0xFF000000, color), 
        )),
    primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xFF000000, color),
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
      primary:MaterialColor(0xFFFFFFFF, colorWhite),
      secondary:Colors.lightBlue,
      tertiary: Colors.lightBlue,
    ),
    tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
      labelColor: MaterialColor(0xFFFFFFFF, colorWhite),
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: MaterialColor(0xFFFFFFFF, colorWhite),
        )),
    primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xFFFFFFFF, colorWhite),
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  ),
```